# Python - Only listing folder names and not full directory

Tags: python

I have a short python script that lists all the folders in a directory however it lists the full path name for each folder. Is there a way to only list the folder name and not the path.

Here is the script:

```
import os

rootdir = xxx
for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
    d = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
    if os.path.isdir(d):
        print(d)
```

Here is the output:

```
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\X01BJ0004
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\X01BJ0005
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\X01BJ0006
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\X01BJ0008
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\X01BJ0026
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\X01BJ0037
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\X01BJ0038
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\X01BJ0039
V:\DATABASES\0 Suspension\Suspensia Pictures\X01BJ0735
```

Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: Print `file` instead of `d`

Comment: Easy fix, and if you want to add anything its (`print(file + ...)`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at this line:

```
os.path.join(rootdir, file)
```

Just looking at it, it "joins" `rootdir` with `file`; it appends `file` to `rootdir`, which is why full directories are being printed.

If you want only the file name to be printed, the line `d = os.path.join(rootdir, file)` should be omitted. Alternatively, just use `file` instead of `d`.